# 80s fantasy movie/show with spherical house that rolls around

Tags: story-identification

The hero was a little girl.  Mostly I remember a spherical house, which rolled around.  It was for kids, but also had some tension in the story.

Saw this in like 1988 or 1989. It was being shown on VCR, so I don't know if it was a show or movie.

Comment: Live action???.

Comment: Yes, it was live action.  House was made of wood.  I wish I remembered something else!

Comment: Interesting question, but how is it Science Fiction or Fantasy question?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 - A spherical house that rolls around definitely sounds like scifi/fantasy.

Comment: @systemdown - Well yes. Probably.

Comment: Were they in the house, running from the house, trying to get into the house, something else?

Comment: Of course there are [real spherical houses](https://www.flickr.com/photos/kapturer/5361780174/?rb=1), and [real rolling houses](http://www.designswan.com/archives/experimental-rolling-house-super-cool.html)...

Comment: Was the show in question, animated?